Computing a probability involving 2 correlated random variables
We toss a coin 12 times, each outcome can be either H or T. For one outcome we have $\mathbb{P}(H)=0.2$. The 2 random variables $X$ and $Y$ are defined as:
$X$=The number of times a toss came up H out of the 12 tosses.
$Y$=The toss number that contained the last H, with 1 being the first toss, up to 12 being the last toss. In the case of no H at all, then $Y=0$.
The question is to compute $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$, as well as $P(X=Y)$.
I am not sure how best to address this, I thought perhaps we could use: $P(X=Y) = P(X=k|Y=k)$ or $P(X=Y)=P(X=k \cap Y=k)$. I can't decide whether it should be expressed as a joint or conditional probability. Can you help me further?

The only paths to achieving $X=Y$ are a string of heads, followed by a string of tails.  $HHTTTTTTTTTT$ for instance (that's the case $X=Y=2$.

Please define your notation in the post (volunteer readers shouldn't have to follow links to understand the question). What are $X$ and $Y$?

@lulu it's not only $X=Y=2$, the $Y$ random variable represents the position of the last $HEAD$.  $X=Y$ is from ${0,...,12}$.

Yes, I was just illustrating one path.

$P(X=Y)=\sum_{k=0}^{12} P(X=Y=k)=\sum_{k=0}^{12}p^k (1-p)^{12-k}=\frac{p^{13}-(1-p)^{13}}{p-(1-p)}$.
